# Google sheets dynamic query to import multiple tabs?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to import data from multiple tabs into a new sheet in Google sheets.  The column headers are the same for each tab, and the data is normalized across all of them.  I can use the importrange function without a problem, but here's the issue:  Every day, a new tab is created, and I don't want to have to edit the query to include a new tab each day.

Is there a way to write an import range function (or similar query) so that it will import EVERY tab in a specified sheet?  e.g. Today, Sheet1 has Tab1, Tab2, Tab3; tomorrow, Sheet1 has Tab1, Tab2, Tab3, Tab4; the next day, Tab1, Tab2, Tab3, Tab4, Tab5.

Answer (score 1):

not possible without scripts. one way would be to generate a formula with a formula. from there you have two options:

- use script to auto-insert formula into the chosen cell on any edit
- copypaste it manually where you need it

there is also the possibility to pre-program non-existent sheet names, so after they are created they will be "activated"

and lastly, go full scripting